# How to pass viewmodel to a viewcontroller using navigationController?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

So i ran into this weird problem.This is my navigation
[navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BASQ5.png)
basically it's LoginVC then NavigationController then HomeVC
i'm trying to change rootViewcontroller form loginVC to Navigation.HomeVC is itself a rootVC for navigationController.
The problem is that i cannot figure out how to pass viewmodel from loginVC to homeVC.
This is how i instaniate NavigationController:

```
loginViewModel.loginStatus.bind { [weak self] isLoggedIn in
        switch isLoggedIn {
        case true:
            print("---login was successfull,transfering to home page---")
            let navController = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "customNavigationController") as! UINavigationController
            self!.view.window?.rootViewController = navController
         
        case false:
            AlertManager.initializeAlert(show: .incorrectData, on: self!)
        default: break
        }
    }
}
```

but i can't figure out how to pass ViewModel to my homeVC

```
init(_ viewmodel: HomeViewModel) {
    self.homeViewModel = viewmodel
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}
```

is there any way to achieve this? or am I doing something fund

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you initialize your `HomeVC` via Storyboard, you cannot initialize it with your `init(viewmodel:)` initializer. Storyboard uses `init(coder:)` initializer to initialize your view controller. So you need set your viewmodel after you initalize your `HomeVC`. And if you set your `HomeVC` to root of your `UINavigationController` on Storybard. You can reach it from `UINavigationController`'s `topViewController` property.

But if you want to use initializer injection approach to pass your dependencies, then you need to initialize your viewcontrollers programmatically. For example:

```swift
loginViewModel.loginStatus.bind { [weak self] isLoggedIn in
        switch isLoggedIn {
        case true:
            print("---login was successfull,transfering to home page---")
            let homeView = HomeVC(HomeViewModel()) // you can replace it with your actual view model
            let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeView)
            self!.view.window?.rootViewController = navController
         
        case false:
            AlertManager.initializeAlert(show: .incorrectData, on: self!)
        default: break
        }
    }
}
```

But, in order to initialize your viewcontrollers programmatically, you need to make your VC's design programatically too or you need to use xib files instead of Storyboard.